# seeing outline on checkmarks when tabbing

Tags: html, css

How do I add a focus outline to checkmarks? For example, when pressing "tab" on the keyboard, the user will see an outline on each content that has been tabbed on.

```css
td:focus {
  outline: 3px dotted #000000;
  outline-offset: 1px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="A1">
                    <span class="hidden">A-1</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="A1" name-"A1" id="A1">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I do not know what exactly I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you want the outline on the checkbox, or the whole td? Your question states one thing `add a focus outline to checkmarks` but your code says another `td:focus`.

Comment: hi, I would like to outline the check box, so I can then select them pressing space. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you want focused, add `tabindex="0"` to the element's tag.

```css
td:focus {
    outline: 3px dotted #000000;
    outline-offset: 1px; color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td tabindex="0" >
            <label for="A1">
                <span class="hidden">A-1</span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="A1" name-"A1" id="A1">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: For completeness, when you change the "0" to another integer > 0, that becomes that element's place in the tab order.  E.g.  `tabindex="3"` makes the element third in the page's tab order.

Comment: Thank you, this works well. However, when I selected  the checkbox with the space bar, it does not check the box. what happen was after tabbing through the boxes, it tabbed through the boxes again without showing an outline checking the box with space bar. If you know why this occurred, feel free to let me know. Thank you so much for your time and help. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector if you want to specify just checkboxes.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline: 3px dotted #000000;
  outline-offset: 1px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="A1">
       <span class="hidden">A-1</span>
        <input type="checkbox" value="A1" name-"A1" id="A1">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```